# Using hub.text_embedding_column with tf.contrib.estimator.RNNClassifier

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to use a module off Tensorflow Hub ([a word embedding module](https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1)) with [tf.contrib.estimator.RNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/RNNClassifier).

## My desired model

```
embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
   key="description", 
   module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")

estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.RNNClassifier(
   sequence_feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
   num_units=[32, 16])
```

Running that returns the following error:

```
ValueError: All feature_columns must be of type _SequenceDenseColumn.
You can wrap a sequence_categorical_column with an embedding_column or indicator_column.
Given (
    type <class 'tensorflow_hub.feature_column._TextEmbeddingColumn'>):
    _TextEmbeddingColumn(key='title_description', module_spec=<tensorflow_hub.native_module._ModuleSpec object at 0x7fb0102a5a90>, trainable=False
)
```

## A working model

Using the TF Hub module works fine with:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[32, 16],
    feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column])
```

Is it possible to use the `nnlm` module with `RNNClassifier`?

Answer (score 1):

The Code corresponding to your Desired Model seems to be working without error in Google Colab with **`Tensorflow Version 1.15`**.

Please find the working code below:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
   key="description", 
   module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")

estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.RNNClassifier(
   sequence_feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
   num_units=[32, 16])
```

Here is the Link for [Github Colab Gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/e9737dd3653973a5861e59f9dba6328a/so_54371669.ipynb).